# Debugging a C# DLL method from MFC

Tags: c#

I have this strange problem. A user is trying my application which is MFC and runs a C# DLL from it.

My beta testing is fine as are many of my users. But for one, the 64 bit crashes.

We did some debugging with message boxes on the MFC side and it seems that this method being called from MFC is the one that is failing:

```
public string[] GetPersonnelNames(bool bSort = true)
{
    List<string> listPersonnelNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Publisher> pkvPair in _PublisherData.PublisherDictionary)
    {
        if (pkvPair.Value.Assignments.IsPersonnel())
            listPersonnelNames.Add(pkvPair.Value.Name);
    }
    if (bSort)
        return listPersonnelNames.OrderBy(p => p).ToArray();

    return listPersonnelNames.ToArray();
}
```

I can't work out why this would fail.

It does call:

```
public bool IsPersonnel()
{
    bool bIsPersonnel = true;

    if (_Assignments == AssignmentType.None ||
        _Assignments == AssignmentType.Demonstration || 
        _Assignments == AssignmentType.Student ||
        _Assignments == (AssignmentType.Demonstration | AssignmentType.Student))
    {
        bIsPersonnel = false;
    }

    return bIsPersonnel;
}
```

But I can't see how it would fail. Am I missing any important sanity checks here?

I don't know how I can further my debugging from the MFC side with this. :(

Comment: Crashes with what message? Is there anything in the Event log? Add proper logging and log the *entire* exception, including its call stack. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Perhaps `_PublisherData` or `PublisherDictionary` are null, or the dictionary contains null values. Or something completely different

Comment: I will ask him. The weird thing is that the 32 bit edition does not crash - same code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How do I "add proper logging and log the entire exception"?

Comment: Add a `try/catch` block to all public functions and use any logging interface you like, or just write something to a file. The DLL's public methods *are* its interface, so you need to ensure that any problems are handled and logged there, even if you intend to propagate the error to the application

Comment: I noticed his XML file was not up to date with the right syntax. I got him to revise it and his errors went away. So yes, there was most likely some null pointer somewhere. I am going to try to find a tutorial for adding logging. I have not done it before. How do you keep the file at a manageable size?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos consider adding a answer based on your comment about implementing logging. I used **SimpleLog** in the end.